# I can't scroll on bootstrap mobile view

Tags: html, css

I'm using bootstrap media but I'm using it only for my navigation, the other code is just ruining my current. When I visit the website from mobile it's zoomed in. I added the media meta `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`, and the website is not zoomed but I can't scroll at all. I viewed every answer here and nothing helped.

If anyone helps I will be very thankful, have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  `maximum-scale.` perverted from zooming. So,  read this to know how to deal with it:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12738